# Spring Data REST : custom query for MongoDB repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, spring-data

I am trying to create a custom query from the [Spring guide : Accessing MongoDB Data with REST](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/) according to the [Reference 4.4 Custom Implementations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.M5/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations). But my custom method is not available from the repository's REST interface (/user/search).

(e.g. Browser is unable to find localhost:8080/user/search/GetByKidsAge?age=1)

Could someone help me to figured this out and give me some suggestions? 
Thanks a lot !!

Below is my code:

**UserRepositoryCustom.java**

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {     

    public List<User> GetByKidsAge(@Param("age") int age);
}
```

**UserRepositoryImpl.java**

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

    @Override
    public List<User> GetByKidsAge(int age) {

        return /*perform query*/;

    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String>, UserRepositoryCustom {

        List<User> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. As soon as you start implementing a repository method manually we cannot know whether `GET` or `POST` is the right HTTP method as whether the execution is idempotent depends on how you implement it.

So the way to go would be implementing a custom controller and expose those methods using the adequate HTTP method. That said, there's a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-206) in our tracker to provide means to define the way these methods should be exposed as well.