# Spring Data MongoDB custom repository method implementation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I followed the instructions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17010650/6164423) to implement custom methods for my MongoDB Repository. However, none of the custom methods appear to be usable (`findAllSeries` and `uploadSomeSeries` do not seem to be found by spring). I have checked the naming

**SeriesRepository:**

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "series", path = "series", excerptProjection = SeriesProjection.class)
public interface SeriesRepository extends MongoRepository<Series, String>, SeriesRepositoryCustom {

    List<Series> findByWinnerId(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

**SeriesRepositoryCustom:**

```
public interface SeriesRepositoryCustom {

    ResponseEntity<Void> createSeries(Series series);
}
```

**SeriesRepositoryImpl:**

```
public class SeriesRepositoryImpl implements SeriesRepositoryCustom {

    private final MongoOperations operations;

    @Autowired
    public SeriesRepositoryImpl(MongoOperations operations) {
        this.operations = operations;
    }

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createSeries(@RequestBody Series series) {
        // ... implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working; via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23212415/6164423) answer, I had to implement a controller for my repository, and delegate the call to the method defined in the custom repository:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class SeriesController {

    private final SeriesRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public SeriesController(SeriesRepository repo) {
        repository = repo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/series", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody Series series) {
        return repository.createSeries(series);
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need **SeriesRepository** interface then in this example ?